# Will bazel truncate or append to an existing build_event_json_file?

Tags: bazel

We have a script which invokes `bazel build` for multiple targets (in this case, compiles some protos, then invokes the main build). In both invocations, we use the parameter `--build_event_json_file`, but we want the output of both runs. Is there a way to get bazel to append to the existing file, or will it always truncate?

Answer (score 0):

[The truncation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/daf5e26c42410fe7708381dd297560d8532ac7e5/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildeventservice/BuildEventServiceModule.java#L776-L778) of `--build_event_json_file` is not configurable.